# App running in Docker container on port 4567 can't be accessed from the outside

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Updating the post with all files required to recreate the setup. – Still the same problem. Not able to access service running in container.

```
FROM python:3

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y ruby rubygems
RUN gem install sinatra

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/

EXPOSE 4567
CMD ruby hei.rb -p 4567
```

**hei.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  'Hello world!'
end
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "4567:4567"
```

I'm starting the party by running `docker-compose up --build .`

**docker ps** returns:
`0.0.0.0:4567->4567/tcp`

**Still, no respons from port 4567. Testing with curl from the host machine.**

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:4567 # and 0.0.0.0:4567
```

**localhost:4567 replies within the containter**

```
$ docker-compose exec web curl localhost:4567
Hello world!%`
```

What should I do to be able to access the Sinatra app running on port 4567?

Comment: No, your ports are correctly exposed and well mapped. That should be enough. If you can print something from python exec when trying to curl, you should see its response. What curl are you trying from your local ?

Comment: I've had a similar problem before. Try with `wget` instead of `curl` inside container.

Comment: Does `curl -v` give you more output? Maybe it is a proxy/DNS issue from outside? Try `curl -v --noproxy 127.0.0.1` then.

Comment: @Ben That's why I suggested `wget`, it will make it easy to detect if it is a proxy issue.

Comment: @Ben, curl -v returns: curl -v localhost:5000
`* Rebuilt URL to: localhost:5000/
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server`

Comment: wget returns: `Connecting to localhost|::1|:5000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... No data received.
Retrying.`

Comment: Is the binding of your server process (i.e. proxy.py) configured to accept non-localhost connections? Already tried to bind to 0.0.0.0? Or any other output by proxy.py within the container?

Comment: To shell into the container, use the `-ti` flag: `docker exec -ti my-container /bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks @RyanGinstrom, I forgot those! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sinatra was binding to the wrong interface.
Fixed by adding the `-o` switch.

`CMD ruby hei.rb -p 4567  -o 0.0.0.0`

Comment: what is the meaing of `-o`

Comment: @hakiko The `-o` switch is for specifying which interface to bind to. Ref the doc at http://sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#bind---server-hostname-or-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

If there is no value assigned to the environment variable APP_ENV ( via (ENV['APP_ENV']), the default environment is "**:development**"

In a development environment with the run settings enabled, sinatra by default bind to the localhost interface of the running machine.

In order to make this service available outside this network, it needs to listen on all interfaces in the running environment. You can get this working by updating the default binding address as "0.0.0.0"

```
FROM ruby:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/
ADD . /usr/src/app/
RUN bundle install
EXPOSE 4567
CMD ["ruby","app.rb","-o", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Please re-read my post. It contains a complete example.